# Can someone explain or show how to combine a bootstrap 3 collapsing top nav and and offcanvas side nav?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the need to put two collapsing menus on one page. One is fixed top nav that collapses in mobile, and the other is a left nav that collapses to an offcanvas (push) menu in mobile. On a phone or tablet there would be two buttons, one for the top menu and another where the side nav would have been.

I have no problem doing one or the other, but I can't seem to combine the two. I think its a conflict of navbar styles, but at the moment my head is so turned around I don't know what to fix.

I've taken two code examples and tried to kludge them together, that's the code I'm working with at the moment. Once I understand how it works, I'll put it into my real page.

I have put together a Fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/jhy1fp5t/ but I don't know how to include Bootstrap and Jasny Bootstrap includes so it doesn't look right, but the html and added css are there.

Here is the html:

```
 <!-- Fixed navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Default</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Static top</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="./">Fixed top <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">


  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="navmenu navmenu-default navmenu-fixed-left offcanvas" id="sidenavigation">
  <a class="navmenu-brand" href="#">Menu</a>  <ul class="nav navmenu-nav"><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li></ul>
 </div>
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-target=".navmenu" data-canvas="body" data-target="#sidenavigation">
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 </button>
</nav>

  <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <h1>Navbar example</h1>
    <p>This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how the default, static and fixed to top navbar work. It includes the responsive CSS and HTML, so it also adapts to your viewport and device.</p>
    <p>To see the difference between static and fixed top navbars, just scroll.</p>

  </div>

</div> <!-- /container -->
```

The worst problem is the behavior of the button for the side nav. It's mysteriously moved to the right now that I've added the top nav. So it's not available when offcanvas shifts the page to the right.

Let me know if I can provide anything else. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out these url hope it helps.

http://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/

http://www.bootply.com/9MPaNP3uj4

http://www.bootply.com/hKRSn65UcS

Comment: I'm not sure yet, but the first example (the "dashboard" page) sure looks like it could be the solution. Thank you!

Comment: The offcanvas is not working in my offline example. I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.5 and  jquery-1.11.2.min.js. Do I need Jasny or something else for the offcanvas?

Comment: No, you don't need any other extra libraries than bootstrap and jquery.

Comment: did you check the first url?

Comment: I did check the first URL, but there is only one menu.Can I use that as a template for a page with two menus?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105290/discussion-between-cheralathan-and-mike-s).